# How to run regular/normal JavaScript code with Knockout JS loops etc

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

lets say you have a simple Knockout loop

```
<!-- ko foreach: data -->
    <div ... show something </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

What is I would like to run some extra JavaScript code on each iteration of the loop (just want to put this code in the view and not the model). Not sure if using script tag is suitable, I don’t think that would work if the code was inside a knockout template as that would already be contained within a script tag.

There are a few other cases where I though been able to run normal JavaScript code inside knockout view would be useful. It is not something I would want to do often however it seems on the rare occasion it would be easier if I could just use regular JS rather than changing other things.

Comment: Just adding to this further, there is one particular situation where I am looping a large array and presenting a list back to the user. At a certain point in this loop I want the remaining rows  in the list to render differently. I could for example have a function inside my model which determines if the row should render one way or another, however this comparison operation is not straight  forward and will require manipulation of 2 strings to make the comparison.

Comment: The other alternative I was considering was using a flag inside the loop. Once the desired condition is met a flag will be set and the remainder of the rows will render differently. (Doing the comparison is cheaper inside the loop as I can just look for an exact string match rather than manipulation the string to determine if one string comes before another, as would be required if I did the comparison in the model). I would rather have the flag stored locally in the loop, rather than storing the flag in the model. Thats why I want to run JS in the knockout loop.

Comment: Besides all this I would rally just like to know a particle method for running normal JavaScript inside knockout view as I might need it on rare occasions in other situations

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be doing that.

The reason is, you'd be mixing business logic and data, and that shouldn't happen.

Comment: Hi Dhaivat, thanks for your reply. I understand what you are saying, it is not something I intend to do on a regular basis. However, without getting into the specifics of my current situation I feel it would be easier to use regular JS inside a knockout loop.

Comment: Also, there are also other cases where I would might like to do this just for debugging and experimentation purposes

Comment: But, knockout doesn't *want* you to do that; that's why they don't let you! There's almost always a better way to debug stuff like this; check out stuff like Chrome's Developer tools or Firebug.

Comment: I am already familiar  with and using Firebug and console.debug() etc. I think you are missing the point, I have already considered other options and in this case it could be worse trying to capture the business logic inside the model as it is a fairly superficial requirement of the business login. But using the model in this situation it would potentially mean doing a complex comparison every iteration of the loop which would not be good for performance and all this could be replaced by 1 or 2 line of JavaScript inside the loop.

Comment: I don't really see why you would care about performance when you're using it for debugging.

Comment: Dhaivat, are you reading what I am saying? I think I have been clear on why on rare occasion I would like to be able to just run few lines of JavaScript inside a knockout view. I would like to know if the knockout framework provides a suitable way of doing that or another suitable approach. I don’t think your quick one liners are helping answer the original question.

Comment: I am afraid you're not reading what I'm saying. I've stated several times that knockout will *not* provide utilities to do this, and you shouldn't be doing this to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to execute a function during a foreach using the afterAdd handler

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: data, afterAdd: myhandler } -->
    <div ... show something </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the useful tip, trying it out now

Comment: Using addAfter was good but not 100% suitable for what I had in mind. I wanted to initialize a flag which is later inspected in the loop. the problem was on the first iteration of the loop the flag was not initialized.

I used this very dirty hack
<!-- ko if: function() { myFlag = false; }() --><!-- /ko -->
I don't like it myself.

Is there an easier way to do this? Would be be worth writing a custom binding that would allow for "inline" javascript? Maybe I am getting way off point.

Comment: @Sam - If you post a fiddle demonstrating what you want to achieve i'm sure we can find an easier way. I've never needed inline js like that before.